# Javascript infinite currying for addition which supports infinite invocations and infinite arguments per invocation?

Tags: javascript, arrays, addition

In a recent interview i was asked to create a function described in below code snippet

```
add(2,3,4)(5,6)(7,8); // Should yield 35
```

As seen in above snippet there's a function named 'add' which can be invoked infinitely and per invocation can accommodate infinite arguments. In the end it should return total sum of all the arguments across all invocations.

Below is a partial solution which requires a final invocation with no arguments.

```js
/**
 * @description
 * infiniteAdd(2,3)(4,5)(6,7)()
 * Above operation yields 27
 */

function infiniteAdd() {
  // Creating closure for subsequent function invocations
  var prevArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  return function() {
    var currArgs = Array.prototype.concat.call(prevArgs, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));

    if (arguments.length < 1) {
      // if no arguments than calculate sum
      return Array.prototype.reduce.call(currArgs,
        function(acc, curr) {
          return acc + curr;
        }
      );
    }
    
    // Recursively call the main function till no more arguments provided
    return infiniteAdd.apply(null, currArgs);
  }
}

console.log(infiniteAdd(2, 3)(4, 5)(6, 7)());
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Hi, could you clarify your question? This is not a service for code review or code writing, so most questions should describe a specific problem with the code, or something specific you want to understand. Have a look at the [help] for more information on how this site works, and what questions are expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement currying function for addition like below

```js
function addition(...args) {
  return args.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
}

function parseAdd(fn) {
  var newFn = fn.bind(null);

  function cal(...args) {
    newFn = newFn.bind(null, ...args);
    return cal;
  }

  cal.toString = () => newFn();

  return (...arg) => {
    newFn = fn.bind(null);
    return cal(...arg)
  }
}

var add = parseAdd(addition)

console.log(add(2, 3, 4)(5, 6)(7, 8))
```